# How to delay the run of SCons source scanner?

Tags: python, build, dependencies, scons

I have a SCons build system set up to build some libraries from C++, as well as Python wrappers for them via SWIG. Then the results are used for data processing, which is also a part of SCons build. The data processing is Python scripts that use the built SWIG-wrapped libraries.

I've set up the dependencies such that data processing starts after all the libraries and wrappers are built, and that works out well. But there's a caveat (you guessed it, right? :) ). I want to add a source scanner, which also uses some of the SWIG libraries to expand the dependencies. The problem is that the scanner runs too soon. In fact, I see it running twice - once at some point early in the build and the other just before data processing starts. So the first scanner run in parallel build typically happens before all the necessary libraries are built, so it fails.

How can I make the scanner itself depend on library targets?

Or, can I delay the scanner run - or eliminate the first scanner run?

Any other ideas?

Comment: So what you want to work is that you build a python module (compiled) with scons, and then load that module in scons and use it?

Comment: Yes, basically. Use it only in scanner, not in build formulation itself. If scanner only ran just before building the target, it would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround *I think* would work is to turn the scanner into a builder that runs the scan process instead of scanner and generates a file that lists all the dependencies. The data processing build would then simply have a scanner to parse that file. I'd expect SCons not attempt to run it early, because it would be aware of the scanned source file being a target of some builder.

Assuming it works, it is still a sub-par solution as it complicates the build set up and adds extra file I/O of a not-so-small file (the dependencies are thousands of files, with long paths).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another potential solution which is kind of another workaround. Is it possible for the scanner to speculate the list of files that will be generated if the *.i swig interface files are passed to it as the "node" argument? This way the scanner doesn't actually need the files to be present to generate the list of dependencies.

In general, I'm wondering if the solution to this problem is to just write logic to aggressively speculate the dependencies before the SWIG libraries are actually generated. I don't assume much info can be gained from looking at the "_*.so" files themselves.

Comment: Scanner "node" is automatically each source file from the associated builder set up, one by one, plus anything that emitter produces. If the specified by Scanner input is missing, build fails. And you still won't be able to use SWIG libs in that scanner.

Comment: Right, however, my understanding is that scons doesn't actually require the dependencies to be present. If a previous builder includes those files as one of its targets, scons will happily execute the build because it has been promised that the relevant dependencies indicated by the scanner will be produced by a builder that will be run before the builder corresponding to the scanner.